# How to understand expectations

Tags: expectation

I am confused about the following expectations. Assume $z_n$ is an n-D random vector with multi-normal distribution and $a$ is an n-D real vector. Are these following two expectations identical?
$$First: E_{z_n}(a^T z_n)^3 $$
$$Second: E_{a^T z_n}(a^T z_n)^3$$

And if they are different, how to compute
$$E_{z_n}((a^T z_n)^2b^Tz_n)=?$$

Thank you very much.

PS: in my understanding, 
$$First: E_{z_n}(a^T z_n)^3=\int (a^T z_n)^3 f(z_n)dz_n $$
$$Second: E_{a^T z_n}(a^T z_n)^3=\int (a^T z_n)^3 g(a^T z_n)da^T z_n$$
where f(z_n) is the density function of $z_n$ and $g(a^T z_n)$ is that of $a^T z_n$.

I have been confused for years. Thank you for any kind help.

Comment: The subscripts are actually meaningless. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you for your comment. I was confused because they are different if you write each of them as integration.